# joomla RTL parameter do not work

Tags: xml, joomla, arabic, right-to-left

I have Joomla 2.5.6 on my localhost , i use template that supported by [Gantry framework](http://www.gantry-framework.org/) so it most [support RTL](http://www.gantry-framework.org/documentation/joomla/advanced/rtl-support-and-limitations) ( Right to Left ) languages like Arabic and Hebrew , to do that we have to enter the file [" language/en-GB/en-Gb.xml "](http://www.php.joomlademo.de/nav.html?installation/language/en-GB/en-GB.xml.source.html) and there we have the xml attribute called rtl , by default it's 0 , when we turn it to 1 , the entire template most turn to rtl by enabling the rtl.css file , my problem that even after change that value to 1 it's sill LTR , it does not change at all , and when i open the source i don't see and rtl.css file loaded , what should i do ?

Answer (score 0):

- I don't think that the Gantry Framework provides a rtl.css file
- Check if inside the template is a RTL file or any reference to something like this (it may be that your template does not support RTL).